# Rebus arone! (We're frying here)

Tags: rebus, knowledge

This is my first rebus. The titre is a crue.

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

### **Hint**

> Note the *knowledge* tag. You may have to use your internet savvy to solve this. Depending on what you know of course!

Comment: A crue, or a clue?

Comment: The crue is *itself* a clue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about

> Roger Wilco and out

In order, the clues are:

> Roger Rabbit.
>  The band Wilco.
>  Ampersand means "and".
>  Someone being thrown out

The clue in the title is

> "We're f***l***ying here" because " roger wilco and out" is pilot jargon.

Comment: Nice! I noticed Chasly said [redacted - the answer] in a comment recently, but then edited it to say something different with the same meaning - that must have been when he got the idea for this puzzle.

Comment: Haha! Yes indeed. That was the very moment.

Comment: You mean "pirot jargon"?

Answer (score 1):

I've accepted ET's answer. If anyone is interested in my thought processes when creating the puzzle, here you are.

### Answer

> Roger, Wilco and Out.  (note all initial caps - as per standard notation)

.

> The  eccentric spelling comes from the first character's speech pattern on the site where I got the picture. A slight wabbity wisp fwom Woger.

.

> "Rebus arone!" - When converted by substituting l for r, we get something that sounds like ""Leave us alone".  The phrase  *Roger, Wilco and Out*, does mean that in a sense. It translates to "Okay, Will do, and Leave us alone, we're fine now."

.

> We're flying here! - This a clue to the fact it is flying jargon when speaking to ATC or another pilot.

.

> The hint about internet savvy.  I'm sure most people on a puzzling site know this already, however, for anyone who hasn't discovered it yet, you can search online using images. Thus, if you don't recognise a picture, you can often find it online. In the case of Wilco, for example, you would have found both [the picture and the name of the band](https://www.google.com/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZitZhsrhnxB9JZ61iaA8UTyhccpuUCaBIbjNJRwFQznzNh9oYAhXDKflrK3yRU0Jjd6yZ1swul-3AhfuCtyB9cKt41dPtD4urnbv40VUvgOm0CFVB1_1acTPCKKBxa4bJHIBy17iVJB_1_1YvdFNR-Aw5tZqRNRYNOkeHG9Kt7CnTWgkgONmbk2kKTD54scpizvo0u_1kWNEr16XzB4J2TA5od3iLtHzDdf3-ISthQUVpeEqomyQW3SitKkKnPrqoZesNnOZ_1hM7pqeAbpdfy6qvbh5ZgOG_1C1wumspPO3zcmLRpJqDH0ubwyRyvIyzA1aum0uqXxbLI1LdVI_1TC53BkpcOnbXIY-rxIzwwIy1NfJTqVn-G-Sl26gM7qBDGSfs-3s1kepSYhyNcLt_1lCfbPJ3gcguoiscRcYXD5rG8Xy4gvDQHKVApePir_1LdoG0KHA8u6cVQ7pHxif2naNcZQUlNnf5aAkZ5ZsHU8YeBOKUmfEvKr4U77gRk6fix5luihNwNL364Ts6Vml975qlifmsLzSrwQ8sGhmm-BV3zyGJb1iKKn6mhuetPwrWfT87ETj3RQ8RaGovMNdCUQyqyIkvrPMri_1YTV7E_1m9xeqVoI_1SbpYmUjqussQlKW3iD9css36d-1SlsDac9J_1mUmxqC2C7ke4BkivFqQGMGc3m4cKYlfDmpgWvTGPx2Tom6Rq-M1BTnM_1lu2CsPEmuh86_13SNiepIYkKsBqAmid50wLhsMCKu0vrEVc8Fo5Rhq8QYXr0A_14odp6NRYl8AL2bDs6qqZw3ieZO9A7NCWgCFpkMS3fjHMZhMOaNUVsJ94_1j6M9Lvjsix3hinfb1bM5UvjmEWaz0zJPu_1pV7eozqH88K9RF-0A_1EIpEb9uwmw78w6HQPeHwuplnSQAcjAhLFL8vnLvHL7U91BPIuh1SVMGWA0MdkRqQYhtCzZjL3G7RCGG3--cMqnC4akfnNDg3AYVmKvT997hCtSenKc9wSzTQMXrAeyJIQiG4dfHJZ_1lNN_1LQDkGso5vOhgFG0SAv7-vuEE06cDT5I6U1KL8gu-f9i07dN-HVdH84AU5sB4Q4vsxOEkxgoNFsDFvHMjgaqR2o3XfKKv1a0ekAR-wnVRidXTYE3MB5zk6vwbEKj-TBMyZGHsKgsWS7ffvAzSLI5AcTZC5ijw2O6DTiojMD5RlHgPfMksN-zd5NsjYX55uHFaMm8Ksq-yYaB4RBWJm1NNHCCnEbSSkuw-HzrxmV5NWY7zh7CmT236zRpEqRCZnAEHsz4os6ReErFTNhz_1dEsKoW1HIMMHgKKHJtGcioJl65MQLhThy4mYKf71GML3kYSNfXkPRC9BM6VMQPsJUjFWpWyJ0Wz3U4JSSctSN8beOajTJuUv2BkT1WJzm9-nGjEtK-ZnsMrrkY4J1ZsaRv9LEZ4bFkoO3sExg&=Search%20by%20image).

Comment: The problem with that "wabbity wisp" is that it's also a stereotypical Far-Eastern "accent".

Comment: Are you saying that no speech idiosyncrasy should ever be used in fictional writing? Not even with respect to a cartoon character? That would be very restrictive. I had no thoughts of anything Far-Eastern and there is zero suggestion in any of my clues of anyone who is far-Eastern.  Can you find anything other than in your own preconceptions (which I personally disown) that I wrote that suggests I intended that?

Comment: For the record, my immediate thought (and nothing I saw in the puzzle gave any indication otherwise) was also that it was meant to mimick especially Japanese people being stereotypically unable to distinguish /r/ and /l/. I’ve never heard Roger Rabbit have any such characteristic in his speech—he frequently pronounces both /r/ and /l/ as /w/, but I’ve never heard him pronounce /l/ as /r/. Until I read your comment here, I didn’t understand where the Japanese aspect fit into the puzzle.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what I can do. I didn't see it that way at all. I first thought of the phrase, Roger, Wilco and Out. Next, I found the pictures, then I wanted to put the word 'rebus' in the title'.  I noticed that 'rebus' sounds something like 'leave us' which, in turn means 'Out'.  This gave me the idea to change other words to match and when I watched a short cartoon I noticed the rabbit speaking a little bit like that. I would be interested to hear from anyone who it actually affects. If necessary I can change it.

Comment: Note: This reminds me a little of the woman who complained that the delivery man was whistling dirty songs.  The problem was in her mind not in that of the person who was whistling.